# torch.utils.data.random_split() is not splitting the data

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I’m not getting split when I use `torch.utils.data.random_split`.

I get correct numbers for `train_size` and `val_size`, but when I do `random_split`, both `train_data` and `val_data` get `full_data`. There is no split happening.

Please help me with this issue.

```
class DeviceLoader(Dataset):

def __init__(self, root_dir, train=True, transform=None):
    self.file_path = root_dir
    self.train = train
    self.transform = transform
    self.file_names = ['%s/%s'%(root,file) for root,_,files in os.walk(root_dir) for file in files]
    self.len = len(self.file_names)
    self.labels = {'BP_Raw_Images':0, 'DT_Raw_Images':1, 'GL_Raw_Images':2, 'PO_Raw_Images':3, 'WS_Raw_Images':4}

def __len__(self):
    return(len(self.file_names))

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    file_name = self.file_names[idx]
    device = file_name.split('/')[5]
    img = self.pil_loader(file_name)
    if(self.transform):
        img = self.transform(img)
    cat = self.labels[device]            
    if(self.train):
        return(img, cat)
    else:
        return(img, file_name)
full_data = DeviceLoader(root_dir=’/kaggle/input/devices/dataset/’, transform=transforms, train=True)
train_size = int(0.7*len(full_data))
val_size = len(full_data) - train_size
train_data, val_data = torch.utils.data.random_split(full_data,[train_size,val_size])
```

Expected result is to split the `full_data` into `train_data`(2000) and `val_data`(500). But instead, I get `full_data`(2500) in both train and val.

Answer (score 6):

From the image below you could see, it actually makes a subset of data but the original dataset is still there. This might be confusing. I did the following on mnist dataset

```py
train, validate, test = data.random_split(training_set, [50000, 10000, 10000])
print(len(train))
print(len(validate))
print(len(test))
```

output:

```
50000
10000
10000
```

[image]